# No variants found for ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle' in Flutter

Tags: flutter

im trying to build flutter apk but when i open it in android to build apk it shows error " No variants found for ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle' "

i have been trying to solve this error changing versions in gradle but nothing worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: same issue after reinstall android studio and import project

Comment: same. what could be the issue @dharmx

Comment: @VDTe found solution. first close android studio then run comman flutter clean in project folder, now be careful first open your android side project  (not flutter) do your android side work. now you can open flutter side project.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same issue after reinstalling android studio, I fixed it by running these two commands

1. flutter clean
2. flutter packages pub cache repair

Hope this helps